# Read via VBA the Excel Function argument descriptions

Tags: excel, vba

Is there a way to read via VBA Function or method the Excel Function argument descriptions? (for built in functions)

I.E. GetArgumentDescription("Function name",1) would read the description of the first argument

When I search all I find is a way to add description for User Defined Functions (not read) https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.macrooptions

Comment: To clarify, you're trying to get argument descriptions for registered UDFs? or the built-in ones?

Comment: The built in ones